# Setting a limit to a double value

Tags: java

I saw this had been answered a few times, but im having a hard time understanding those answers, and and even harder time implementing them into my program. The program essentially calculates the sum of 2 numbers and converts them into a percentage, but the value cant exceed 75. I used the if method to solve this, but in the book it says "(Hint: use math.min)", so im afraid if i don't I will lose points on the project. If anyone can help me implement a max value, that would be wonderful.

```
package week2assignments;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question4 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     int memberRent;
     int memberRef;
     double memberDisc;


     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


     System.out.println("How many rentals has the user made?");
     memberRent = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println("How many members has the user reffered?");
     memberRef = in.nextInt();



     memberDisc = memberRent + memberRef;
     if(memberDisc > 75)
     {
         memberDisc = 75;
     }


     System.out.printf("Member has a discount of: ");
     System.out.printf("%.2f \n", memberDisc);




   }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the `min` method does and returns? Have you thought about how that could be used to limit a number?

Comment: Try to implement `min` function and compare it to your code. You will easily spot similarities.

Comment: The contract of the min function is something like this "min(a, b) = a or b". Think of what a or b could be. I'll give you a hint, one of them is 75.